# Why is this update creating a deadlock?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

I have these queries:

(This one was deadlocked)
[image]

And this one:

```
update tbldealerativacao 
    set flagusado = 0 from tbldealerativacao WITH (NOLOCK) 
    inner join tbldealerusuario WITH (NOLOCK) on tbldealerativacao.coddealer=tbldealerusuario.coddealer 
where codusuario = 34527
```

But , Isn't this an update? Why is this a deadlock?

The update 2 shoudnt wait for the first one?

this is the graph:

[image]

I created this test index to see if I can't solve the problem but with no success ( is was using the same index before the Image below, only with 2 more fields in the include ):

```
create index IX_TESTE
on tbldealerativacao ( flagusado,coddealer,iddealerativacao)
```

Obs1: I know WITH(NOLOCK) is a bad habit from programmers. I just got this query and I will try to not use it.

EDIT 1:

In the execution plan, I have this index scan for this query:

```
Update tbldealerativacao 
Set flagusado = 0 from tbldealerativacao WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join tbldealerusuario WITH (NOLOCK) 
  on tbldealerativacao.coddealer = tbldealerusuario.coddealer 
    Where codusuario = 33826
```

[image]

Could this be the problem? 2 sessions waiting for the lock_x?

this is the index:

```
create  index IX_codusuario
    on tbldealerativacao ( coddealer,flagusado )
```

---

EDIT 2:

this is with whoisactive:

[image]

---

EDIT 3:

This is now with no `with(nolock)`

[image]

---

EDIT4:

Here is the create table queries:

> Tbldealerativacao

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerAtivacao](
    [CODDEALER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CODJOB] [smallint] NULL,
    [FLAGUSADO] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CHAVEALEAT] [float] NULL,
    [idDealerAtivacao] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblDealerAtivacao] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idDealerAtivacao] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerAtivacao]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblDealerAtivacao_tblJob] FOREIGN KEY([CODJOB])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblJob] ([CodJob])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerAtivacao] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblDealerAtivacao_tblJob]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerAtivacao] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblJobAtivacao_FLAGUSADO]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [FLAGUSADO]
GO
```

> Indexes ( Some names are dumb names because I was trying to create them for test purposes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ALL] ON [dbo].[tblDealerAtivacao] 
(
    [CODDEALER] ASC,
    [CODJOB] ASC,
    [FLAGUSADO] ASC,
    [CHAVEALEAT] ASC,
    [idDealerAtivacao] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_coddealer] ON [dbo].[tblDealerAtivacao] 
(
    [FLAGUSADO] ASC,
    [CODDEALER] ASC
)
```

> tbldealerusuario

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerUsuario](
    [CODDEALER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CODJOB] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [CODUSUARIO] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblDealerUsuario] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CODDEALER] ASC,
    [CODJOB] ASC,
    [CODUSUARIO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerUsuario]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblDealerUsuario_tblJob] FOREIGN KEY([CODJOB])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblJob] ([CodJob])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerUsuario] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblDealerUsuario_tblJob]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerUsuario]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblDealerUsuario_tblUsuario] FOREIGN KEY([CODUSUARIO])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblUsuario] ([CODUSUARIO])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDealerUsuario] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblDealerUsuario_tblUsuario]
GO
```

> Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_codusuario] ON [dbo].[tblDealerUsuario] 
(
    [CODUSUARIO] ASC
)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64698/discussion-on-question-by-rafael-piccinelli-why-is-this-update-creating-a-deadlo).